# How to properly setup an architecture for working with Hasura metadata in different branches?

Tags: git, hasura, hasura-cli

Hasura has a great system of incremental migrations of database schema.

You set it up, create a new branch, launch console from cli, do your changes and get a bunch of migration files.
Add those files to git, merge them with master, when you are ready and do 'migrate apply ...' to apply those changes to production DB.

Now, with metadata it does not work this way. Every time you launch hasura cli and do anything worth tracking - metadata file will updated.

Here is an example of the problem I am facing.
There are two similar databases (hasura installations) - PROD and DEV.

I create to branches from master - branch A and branch B. Both will be working with DEV database.
I start working on branch A, add some tables, add some permissions and relations. I end up with a bunch of migrations and metadata file that contains setup that was in master + my changes.
When I finish with the branch, potentially I should do 'hasura migrate apply' & 'hasura metadata apply' and all changes will be moved to prod database.

My friend start working on a branch B, add some tables, add some permissions and relations. He end up with a bunch of migrations and metadata file that contains setup that was in master + his changes + *my changes*.
So when he finishes with the branch,  'hasura migrate apply' will add all the stuff that he wants, but 'hasura metadata apply' will throw and error, because some of the clauses in it will be based on tables that where never migrated (tables created in branch A).

How should I sync metadata?

Answer (score 0):

Both of you are working on DEV, you do not need to do 'hasura migrate apply' etc. The changes you are doing are already done on DEV. When you are done with your changes merge to PROD branch and then do the migrations and applying metadata on PROD. These are to replicate the changes done on DEV to PROD.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. 
The problem is the last step - merging, applying metadata and schema to PROD. 
If only one branch is merged metadata in it will (potentially) be containing information about schema elements (e.g. tables) that are not covered by migration. This will make `metadata apply` fail.

Comment: Yes, It might fail. You can either then resolve the inconsistencies then or have a STAGING env to verify before PROD

Comment: Do you think there is a way to automatically resolve those inconsistencies? Otherwise it basically means that before each merge I should go through the tables.yaml file and fix it. And errors are smaller problem - if, for example, in DEV some column was publicly accessible (for tests) - those changes will go to PROD too.

Comment: Inconsistencies can be resolved from the Hasura portal itself. It gives options to delete.  Migrations are to for creating exact copies, so if something is public in DEV it will go public in PROD